# Sorting argument array for dynamically called method

Tags: php, arrays, reflection

I'm using reflection to dynamically call methods.

```
$object = new $class;
$reflector = new ReflectionMethod($class, $method);
$reflector->invokeArgs($object, $arguments);
```

The `$arguments` array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [fooparam] => false
    [id] => 238133
)
```

The method called could be:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function myMethod ($id, $fooParam)
    {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

The problem is that everything comes from frontend designers, depending on `data-*` attributes, `href`... so `$arguments` array has arbitrary sorting.

How can I sort this array to match method parameters?
O maybe, is there a better solution? Named parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ReflectionMethod::getParameters()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php) to get a list of arguments and filter map them to their corresponding position, e.g.:

```
$sorted_args = array_map(function($param) use($arguments) {
    $name = $param->getName();
    if (!isset($arguments[$name]) && !$param->isOptional())
        throw new BadMethodCallException("Argument '{$name}' is mandatory");

    return isset($arguments[$name]) ? $arguments[$name] : $param->getDefaultValue();
}, $reflector->getParameters());
```

You could also use a simple `foreach` loop, it's up to you.

Then invoke the method with `$sorted_args` instead:

```
$reflector->invokeArgs($object, $sorted_args);
```

Comment: Working! Just a marginal note for people who is posting `data-*` attributes like me. If your `$arguments` keys become lowercase, just `strtolower($name)` anywhere before checking if `!isset($arguments[$name])`. I`ll edit the answer to illustrate this issue. Thanks!